# How to show that this function is integrable

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

Let $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R  $ a function defined by
$$ f(x) =  
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $\exists p \in \mathbb N, x = \frac 1p$} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases} $$
I have to show that $f$ is integrable in $[0,1]$.
I tried using Cauchy criterion but no luck so far. any hints are welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was copying latex expressions and I forgot to change them, fixed now =)

Comment: What have you seen about Riemann-integrability? The function is bounded and defined on a closed interval and it is discontinuous in an infinite, but _countable_ number of points; hence Riemann-integrable.

Comment: $\{x:f(x)\neq0\}$ has measure 0.

Comment: You could make partitions that are finer and finer, age show that the upper sum and lower sum converge to the same value.

Comment: We started by the Darboux integral, and we defined that a bounded function is integrable iff the the upperand the  lower sums converge to the same value, then we showed that darboux definition of an integrable function is equivalent to Cauchy criterion, and we used it again to show that this is the same as the definition Riemann used to define integral, and other propositions like if functions is continuous then it is integrable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small real.

$f $ is integrable at $[\frac {\epsilon}{2},1] $ as a stairs function, thus there exist a subdivision $s_1$ of $[\frac {\epsilon}{2},1] $ such that

$U (f,s1)-L (f,s1)<\frac {\epsilon}{2}$

put $s=s_1\cup \{0\} $

we have

$$U (f,s)-L (f,s)\leq $$

$$\frac {\epsilon}{2}+U (f,s_1)-L (f,s_1) <\epsilon$$

Comment: do I need to prove that restriction of f in  [epsilon/2,1] is a stairs function?

Comment: it is constant in each $(\frac {1}{p+1},\frac {1}{p}) $